# Getting type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' error when using BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

**Scenario**

I am trying to use flutter_bloc for state management in my Flutter app. In my app, I have a button that will appear only if the entered email is valid. For this, I have a `_isEmailValid` variable initially set to *false* which updates to *true* once the entered email is valid.

The button that I want to display is is wrapped in a `BlocBuilder` as follows:

```
BlocBuilder<ShowButtonBloc, ShowButtonState>(
                    builder: buildSubmitButton,
                  ),
```

where `buildSubmitButton` is as follows:

```
Widget buildSubmitButton(BuildContext context, ShowButtonState state) {
    if (!_isEmailValid) {
      return const SizeBox();
    } else {
      return GradientButton(
        onTap: () {
          // Navigation logic
        },
        text: labels[31]["labelsText"],
      );
    }
  }
```

Now, `GradientButton` is a custom widget which takes in a **String** parameter called `text`. When I pass a string such as `text: "Proceed"`, the app runs fine, however, when I try to assign a string from a different map variable, I get the error:

**The following _TypeError was thrown building BlocBuilder<ShowButtonBloc, ShowButtonState>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<ShowButtonBloc?>], state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<ShowButtonBloc, ShowButtonState>#e4f0a):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'**

Here, labels is a `final List<Map<String, dynamic>>` and `labels[31]["labelsText"] = "Proceed"`. The business requires me to store the text in a map for now, and later fetch these contants from an API, which is why can't merely assign static text to the button.

Here is how my Bloc looks like:

*show_button_state.dart*

```
class ShowButtonState {
  final bool show;
  const ShowButtonState({
    required this.show,
  });
}
```

*show_button_event.dart*

```
class ShowButtonEvent {
  final bool show;
  const ShowButtonEvent({
    required this.show,
  });
}
```

*show_button_bloc.dart*

```
class ShowButtonBloc extends Bloc<ShowButtonEvent, ShowButtonState> {
  ShowButtonBloc()
      : super(
          const ShowButtonState(show: false),
        ) {
    on<ShowButtonEvent>(
      (event, emit) => emit(
        ShowButtonState(show: event.show),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Request**

I would like to know why I'm getting the error when I pass the string from the variable, and how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with your BLoC.

```
labels[31]["labelsText"]
```

did not exist.

Since you did not post that part, it's hard to help you any further. Make sure this references something that exists. *Are* there 32 labels (remember, the first one is at index 0)? Does the 32nd *have* a property "labelsText" that is set to a text? Check for typos, too.

Comment: You are right, it was a typo on my part. The property in question was `labelText` and not `labelsText`. Fixed the typo and things work now. Thanks a lot.